# Filling dynamically generated ListBox in IronPython

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, ironpython

I have some datasets from a python script that I want to visualize using WPF. My Layout consists of multiple dynamically generated ListBoxes (a new is added by pressing the '+' button):
[image: Example Window, after pressing the button once]

I managed to bind the ListBoxes themselves to an `ObservableCollection` and adding new elements works fine. However, I can't find out how I can fill these ListBoxes with values? (assume the values are strings or simple dicts in a list). I assume it needs to be done within my `HDBox` class, but I do not know how to access the XAML-elements from within that class etc.

**XAML:**

```
<Window 
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
   Title="WpfApplication1" Height="300" Width="500">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30px"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25px"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10" Grid.Column="0" >
        <ItemsControl Name="stHDBox">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
                        <ListBox Name="roomEntries" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="200">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Entry}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="AddHDButton" Content="+" Margin="0,0,0,10" Grid.Row="1" Click="AddHDButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="24" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**Python Code:**

```
import wpf
from System.Windows import Application, Window
from System.Collections.ObjectModel import ObservableCollection

class HDBox:
    index = 0
    def __init__(self):
        # Not sure about that part, doesn't seem to work
        rooms = ObservableCollection[type("")]()
        self.roomEntries.ItemsSource = rooms

class MyWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        # Create 1 HDBox by default
        self.hDBoxes = ObservableCollection[type(HDBox)]()
        self.hDBoxes.Add(HDBox)
        self.hDBoxes[0].index = 0
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication1.xaml')
        self.stHDBox.ItemsSource = self.hDBoxes

    # '+' Button to add new boxes
    def AddHDButton_Click(self, sender, e):
        i = len(self.hDBoxes)
        self.hDBoxes.Add(HDBox)
        self.hDBoxes[i].index = i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

---

**Edit:** 
As there is some editing going on, I provide the current python code here:

```
import wpf
from System.Windows import Application, Window
from System.Collections.ObjectModel import ObservableCollection

class HDBox:
    index = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop = ObservableCollection[type("")]()
        self.prop.Add("test")

    @property
    def YourProperty(self):
        return self.prop

    @YourProperty.getter
    def YourPropertyGetter(self):
        return self.prop

class MyWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        # Create 1 HDBox by default
        self.hDBoxes = ObservableCollection[type(HDBox)]()
        self.hDBoxes.Add(HDBox)
        self.hDBoxes[0].index = 0
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication1.xaml')
        self.stHDBox.ItemsSource = self.hDBoxes

    # '+' Button to add new boxes
    def AddHDButton_Click(self, sender, e):
        i = len(self.hDBoxes)
        self.hDBoxes.Add(HDBox)
        self.hDBoxes[i].index = i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

Answer (score 1):

The `HDBox` class should have an `ObservableCollection<T>` property that you bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListBox` in the `ItemTemplate` to:

```
<ListBox Name="roomEntries" ItemsSource="{Binding YourProperty}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="200">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Entry}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You then populate each `ListBox` with items by adding items to the corresponding `HDBox` collection property.

Comment: I added `self.YourProperty = ObservableCollection[type("")]()` and `self.YourProperty.Add("test")` to the constructor of HDBox, but it still doesn't add a string to the ListBox. Do I need to do anything with the `Binding Entry` Textblock? Is the path to YourProperty incomplete?

Comment: If you are adding simple strings to the "YourProperty" collection, the binding in the ItemTemplate should look like this: <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />

Comment: I did that, but get the error message `System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'YourProperty' value (type 'Object') from '' (type 'OldClass'). BindingExpression:Path=YourProperty; DataItem='OldClass' (HashCode=36058338); target element is 'ListBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable') InvalidOperationException:'System.InvalidOperationException: Property path is not valid. 'System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject' does not have a public property named 'Items'.`

Comment: What is OldClass? It seems like you should add YourProperty to this class.

Comment: I have no idea what this class is. My entire code is posted in the question, and I surely never named a class `OldClass`

Comment: Then it must be some IronPython thing I guess. If you temporaily remove the ListBox and replace it with the following TextBlock, what does it say?
<TextBlock Text="{Binding YourProperty.Count}" />

Comment: There is no more error message, but the window stays empty.

Comment: Are you sure that YourProperty is a property with a public getter?

Comment: I wasn't even aware that a getter is needed (as I said, the entire codebase is in the question). Now I created something that looks more like a getter, which got rid of the error message. Still, no text visibile :(

Comment: I am not sure about the IronPython syntax but you could try to implement your property as suggested here: http://langexplr.blogspot.se/2011/02/ironpython-wpf-data-binding-with.html. As far as WPF is concerned you can only bind to a public property.

Comment: Regular Python doesn't really have a keyword for private/public stuff. I never used IronPython, C#, WPF, or even VisualStudio. So things might be different here. I'll try to make sense of your link, thank you.